# how to print search patterns as column in awk

Tags: awk

I have an input file with collection of `/proc/meminfo` results from different VMs. Now I need to compile the result in summary table.

Exmaple:Expected output

```
MemAvailable    MemFree
1234            223
2345            231
2312            229
9822            3466
5689            2376
```

I tried using following logic and realized that it's not correct, can anyone help me to correct it?

```
awk '/MemAvailable/{memA=$2;next} /MemFree/{memF=$2;next} {print memA,memF}' input_file
```

Note: Input data can be generated by running `cat /proc/meminfo` twice or thrice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly you want to print the values of available memory and total memory information from file named `/proc/meminfo`
following may help you in same.

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "MemAvailable\tMemFree"}/MemTotal/{val=$2;next} /MemFree/{print val,$2}' OFS="\t\t" /proc/meminfo
```

Comment: I would suggest to use `printf` instead of tabs for formatting. tabs are _evil_ but I don't want to start a [holy war](https://www.jwz.org/doc/tabs-vs-spaces.html).

Comment: @kvantour, sure sir, by seeing OP's output I thought to put TAB into output. We could do space also output delimiter by removing OFS="\t" in above code.